How to add hours (e.g. 10 hours) to 'creation_time' & 'last_modified_time' columns from metatables in Big Query and convert them to timestamp?
How to add hours (e.g. 10 hours) to 'creation_time' & 'last_modified_time' columns from metatables in Big Query and convert them to timestamp?
The 'creation_time' or the 'last_modified_time' field format is like this 1649719596125.

HI @toking , In another approach to convert milliseconds to a timestamp, we can use the ‘TIMESTAMP_SECONDS’ function along with 'Div’ to convert milliseconds to seconds . DIV(creation_time,1000) - it’s convert miliseconds to second by dividing by 1000 .
SELECT *, TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(creation_time,1000)),Interval 10 hour) AS creation_time_added_hours .

Please Let me know if this helps or not ?

It looks like the values supplied, being 13 digits, are using Epoch Time (Unix time) in milliseconds, i.e. how many milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
If they were in microseconds they would have 16 digits.
If they were in seconds they would have 10 digits.
Here's how you go about your challenge.

Convert the incoming Epoch value to a human-readable date format using TIMESTAMP_MILLIS()
Add the 10 hours as an INTERVAL to that value, using TIMESTAMP_ADD()

WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(1649719596125 AS INT64) AS creation_time,
    CAST(1649719596125 AS INT64) AS last_modified_time
)

SELECT 
  *,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) as creation_time_human_readable,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) as last_modified_time_human_readable,

  --Now convert the values and add the required interval
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) AS creation_time_modified,
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) AS last_modified_time_modified
FROM tmp;


I am assuming that the timestamp fields you describe are Unix epoch encoded (see here).  We can convert a Unix value to a timestamp using the TIMESTAMP_MILLIS function.  Another StackOverflow question titled Convert UNIX time to timestamp in BigQuery provides additional information.
To add 10 hours, we can then use the TIMESTAMP_ADD function ... for example:
TIMESTAMP_ADD(<originalTimeStamp>, INTERVAL 10 HOUR)


The value supplied is Unix time encoded in milliseconds, not seconds, so your suggestion to use TIMESTAMP_SECONDS fails.
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1649719596125) returns error:
Error: TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00..
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1649719596125) succeeds.

TY ... have updated the response to reference TIMESTAMP_MILLIS instead of TIMESTAMP_SECONDS
